# Is there a way to tell if a planet is about to self-implode in 24 hours?

Tags: planets, space-travel

So, my main characters are kidnapped by a group of anarchist anti-government terrorists, who like cruel and unusual punishments. Instead of just shooting them or blasting them out of an airlock, the terrorists have a different idea. Their home is a small planetoid, Zuron, that is about to collapse on itself. The terrorists knock out my main characters, erase their memories of being captured, and send them down to Zuron, which is going to collapse in about 24 hours. My question is:

**Would there be any signs that a planet is going to collapse in 24 hours that my characters could notice?**

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will relate almost entirely to the reason why the planet is imploding as well as the composition of the planet itself.  Can you provide a bit of that?

Comment: As @Naryna pointed out, what is the reason for the self implosion? That information will tell if it is detectable or not. On a side note, have you considered registering your account?

Comment: @L.Dutch: The planets Core was mined nearly to depletion, and it’s starting to implode

Comment: I haven't done the math, but I fear that a planet with those qualities will have lost the ability to support life long before the crust collapses.

Comment: @Narnya: Their locked inside space suits

Comment: There may be increasing tremors that signal the impending collapse. But asteroid's collapse would be a slow and not so violet event, unless people are trapped underground.

Comment: Instead of commenting over and over to add details you obviously missed, edit the question. You cannot expect us to go through all your comments to get the full context

Comment: This really need all the details edited into the question.  Too much is not present to actually answer it.  Based on some comments, the answer is likely, "Yes, because plot."

Comment: To hollow out the core of a planet requires technology **far** beyond anything we know how to build--the pressures are **far** beyond what any material structure can withstand.

Answer (score 7):

**A planet has already "imploded"**

Planets (and smaller round bodies) are too large for the structural integrity of its material to hold a shape. It has collapsed under its weight, becoming essentially a pile of mush (technically, it's in *hydrostatic equilibrium*) which will then assume a spherical shape under gravity.

I can't think of any way for a planet to *further* implode, so there wouldn't be signs since it couldn't happen. You would need some sort of completely fictional mechanism for this to happen, and without specifying how it would work, it's impossible to say what its signs would be. You'd basically be coming up with some form of magic and it's up to you to decide whether there would be signs.

Comment: No, no no, the planet was “rigged”. I forgot to add this and I’m sorry, but the terrorist put spires inside the planets empty core, and the spires are slowly collapsing under the planets weight

Comment: @DTCooper I fear that is likely your answer.  If the planet it rigged to collapse, then it is the rigging that will create the signs.  If the rigging is good, there will be no indication, if it is bad there will be signs.  It is no longer a natural implosion in any sense.

Comment: Yes, check `IsZuronAboutToImplode.com`. It's a static page that says "No". ;)

Answer (score 4):

> [*The planets Core was mined nearly to depletion, and it’s starting to implode*](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/114865/is-there-a-way-to-tell-if-a-planet-is-about-to-self-implode-in-24-hours/114897#comment351621_114865)

Let's talk about the idea of hollowing out a planet so much so that it collapses like a mineshaft with the supports knocked out. This means removing *a lot* of material. More than I think you realize.

Let's use the [Earth's inner core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_core) for example. It's roughly a solid iron-nickel ball under intense heat and pressure. The pressure keeps it solid despite the high temperature. Just working at those pressures and temperatures requires some unobtanium technology. We'll assume you have that.

Mining it, moving it to the surface, and presumably off-planet requires moving all that mass up and out of the planet's gravity well. This uses *a lot* of energy. How much depends on how much mass we're talking about. So to work out the mass we multiply its volume by its density.

[The Earth's inner core is estimated to have a density of about 13,000 kg/m^3](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=density+of+earth%27s+inner+core), about 10% more dense than lead. The inner core is about 1200 km or 1.2e6 m in radius.

$$mass = 13,000 \frac{kg}{m^3} \times \frac{4 \pi (1,200,000m)^3}{3}$$

That's 9.4e22 kg, about 20% more than the mass of the Moon. Let's say they mine just 1% of this material, 9.4e20 kg which is "only" the mass of Ceres.

We can assume if they're trashing the planet this hard they're taking the material somewhere else. Getting this mined material off planet is the same as launching Ceres from Earth into space. This is *a lot* of energy. Earth's escape velocity is 11km/s or 11,000 m/s. We can figure out how much energy using the kinetic energy equation for velocity and mass. A Joule is $kg \times \frac{m^2}{s^2}$

$$energy = 1/2 \times 9.4e20 kg \times (11,000 m/s)^2$$

That's 5.7e28 Joules. This is *a lot* of energy. And this is the *minimum* energy needed. An actual launch will use more. How much more depends on the tech in your world.

If we assumed perfect mass-energy conversion tech, $E = mc^2$, in your world (and somehow dissipating the heat) that still needs 6.375e11 kg. If you perfectly converted all 7 billion humans on Earth into energy you would still be short by about 50%. That's about 2 minutes of the *total* output of energy from the Sun (not what the Earth receives, total).

Point is, you're well into unobtanium sci-fantasy tech. Any reality-based explanation will fall flat with the kinds of energies you're throwing around. You'll have to flesh out how the technology works in this world for us to answer. Or you'll have to scale things waaaay back.